# Cannot select option from dropdown after the first time I run the test

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I'm writing protractor tests and I have a really weird issue. I need to click on a dropdown and select an item from it. I have a few other tests to select items from dropdown and they all work fine. But on this page, it works during the first run and from the second time, it clicks open the drop down but doesn't select the item.

It times out but doesn't show any error like not finding the element.

```
- Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
      at ontimeout (timers.js:475:11)
      at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:310:5)
  (node:24118) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): CancellationError: ControlFlow was reset
```

Has anyone experienced anything like this? What can I try to make this work?

Comment: there may be lots of reasons. Why don't you use post you error and html at the moment of failure?

Comment: it doesn't show any specific error. It times out.

Comment: set up a debugging config in your IDE and run tests line by line